# Witches always find it funny to curse me

Tags: riddle

> I am a source of good ideas
> But I am also a source of great tragedy
> Witches always find it funny to curse me
> Creeps and thieves never seem to like my presence
> But only if others are around with me
> Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

What am I?

Hint

> The witch line refers to a double meaning within the word curse.

Comment: 'thieves'? or is that spelling intentional?

Comment: @DavidConrad Accidental typo. I will fix in a moment.

Answer (score 12):

I know it's not close to Shotstic's first answer, which the author said was close to the actual answer, but here we go anyway.

I think you may be..

> an **apple**.

---

*I am a source of good ideas*
*But I am also a source of great tragedy*

> In Genesis 2:16-17, God forbids Adam and Eve to eat from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil. Generally the fruit of this tree is portrayed as an apple.

*Witches always find it funny to curse me*

> In multiple fairy tales witches poison or curse apples so that when the victim takes a bite, they suffer some sort of a curse.

*Creeps and thieves never seem to like my presence*
*But only if others are around with me*

> In medieval times, people would throw rotten food at pilloried thieves as a form of humiliation. I suppose creeps could have also suffered the same fate. Apples would have been a common choice of rotten fruit to toss.

*Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question*

> I think this is a red herring. "Mirror" in this context could mean opposite of, or response to. The response to a question is an answer. But answer to what question? Well what question follows on the following line? "What am I?" So I believe this is a red herring which basically says that I am the answer to the question "What am I?" Also, most apples are red like this red herring. :P

Comment: `a source of good ideas` can also refer to the story of how Newton got inspired to describe gravity.

Comment: I thought a source of good ideas would be giving an apple to a teacher, they are the source, but your reasoning is better.

Comment: This answer is brilliant, although I suspect not the intended answer since the "Most important of all" part is too much of a stretch.  However, the shape of an apple *does* look something like a question mark together with its mirror image... ?

Comment: This is not the intended answer but good try!

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure the answer here is...

> A lightbulb

All credit goes to @Shotstic for the idea, some explanations

I am a source of good ideas

> Ideas are often presented with a lightbulb over your head

But I am also a source of great tragedy

> Revealed out: danger of light bulbs burning out

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> This is a longshot here, but I'm gonna go with this: 
>  "How many Witches does it take to change a light bulb? Depends on what you want to change it into." And many other related jokes

Creeps and theives never seem to like my presence

> Thieves always prefer to stay away from the light, for obvious reasons

But only if others are around with me

> Reffers to interrogation room? Where there is often (as presented in movies) one single lamp and the policemen making questions to the 'thief.' Also, light doesn't matter if no one is around to see the perp. the others aren't other lightbulbs, but witnesses.

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> The reverse of a question mark forms a lightbulb

Comment: possibility for tragedy: ["A product that refuses to wear out is a tragedy of business"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1825163/)

Comment: You got it! Figure out the two you are unsure of, and rethink the many with me line and I will accept. Great job!

Comment: "But I am also a source of great tragedy"...... is the mankind overuse of it, the energy crisis will be caused in one day? "Witches always find it funny to curse me"......when the lightbulb broke, it looks like a disaster coming from the evil to your head??? :) just the guess.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced with that last one, need bit more time to figure out the one from the witches and the 'many with me', was pretty sure about this one :(

Comment: Really? This is the answer? :/

Comment: Source of great tradegy is just the danger of light bulbs burning out (I revealed this in another answer). As for witches.... Think of the word "curse". What could it mean in other ways? Why would it be funny?

Comment: I'm kinda lost with the "curse" thing...maybe cus I'm not native english :S

Comment: @MarioGarcia oh. Well it has to do with a double meaning of the word curse. Thats all I will say. If you still cannot get it tomorrow I might post another hint.

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be

> Light

I am a source of good ideas:

> Light bulbs in cartoons, "bright" ideas etc.

But I am also a source of great tragedy:

> Blinding light(literally), UV light causing cancer, light can do a lot of damage.

Witches always find it funny to curse me:

> I'm not sure if witches curse light, I can imagine something like that happening but I'm not an expert on witches either so I wouldn't know.

Creeps and thieves never seem to like my presence:

> They usually like to lurk/operate in the dark

But only if others are around with me:

> If there aren't any people around the light doesn't actually matter.

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question:
I'm totally stuck on this though, can't think of anything.

---

Second try:

> You're a (light) torch

I am a source of good ideas:

> same as before? Bright ideas

But I am also a source of great tragedy:

> torches cause fire, fire causes destruction/death

Witches always find it funny to curse me:

> They are burned at the stake

Creeps and thieves never seem to like my presence:

> Same as before, exposure

But only if others are around with me:

> You can only be exposed when people are around. This could also point at people(carrying torches) chasing(or anything else really) the creeps/thieves.

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question:
Again, I don't know what this means. Mirrors+torches were used to direct light but I can't figure out the question part. Then again, I'm not a native English speaker and might be looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: Sorry, but I am an object. Though you seem to be close to identifying me...

Comment: I also thought of this answer Mirror of a question could have been: If you have a question you're in the dark about something, the opposite or 'mirror' would be light.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be

> Heart

I am a source of good ideas

> As intent always comes from heart

But I am also a source of great tragedy

> pain is always felt by heart

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> curse the heart in witchcrafts

Creeps and theives never seem to like my presence

> creeps and thieves don't have a heart

But only if others are around with me

> could be depicting the shape of the heart as being full.

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> heart shape is like a reflection of a question mark ?

Comment: Nope but great try!

Answer (score 2):

Are you...

> the eye?

I am a source of good ideas
But I am also a source of great tragedy

> Seeing something might inspire you, but if there is great tragedy to be seen you will cry.

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> There is the "bad eye", and a curse of blindness is not fun to have.

Creeps and theives never seem to like my presence
But only if others are around with me

> They don't like to be seen, but if there is only one person, they might get away with it.

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> "I can see the question in your eyes!"

Comment: Nope, but very good thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

Is it?

> a book

I am a source of good ideas

> books are a source of knowledge that could be used for good

But I am also a source of great tragedy

> books are a source of knowledge that could be used for evil

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> very often in tales books are cursed

Creeps and theives never seem to like my presence

> single books lying around aren't exactly valuable

But only if others are around with me

> a library could very well mean that the owner of the library has other valuables around

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> books can pose questions, but very often explain the answers

Comment: Sorry, but no cigar. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is really a shot in the dark. 
You are

> A dog!

I am a source of good ideas

> Dogs are experimented upon(As in pavlov experiment/ think sherlock holmes)

But I am also a source of great tragedy

> Biting of a dog can be lethal at times..

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> In tales, witches usually curse people to turn into animals..

Creeps and theives never seem to like my presence

> Of course they don't like to see a dog in a house.

But only if others are around with me
Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> Can't make sense of this...

Answer (score 2):

I thinkt it's

> love

I am a source of good ideas

> Many good ideas are motivated by love.

But I am also a source of great tragedy

> Many tragedies are caused by rejected love.

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> Witches have spells and potions to induce love. Many spells are broken by love.

Creeps and theives never seem to like my presence

> Creeps and thieves try to go unnoticed, love implies attention.

But only if others are around with me

> Creeps might want to watch love, thieves like the distraction it entails.

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> Love answers all things.

Comment: Answers anything, yeah...

Answer (score 1):

it could be

> **jesus**

I am a source of good ideas

> every good ideas originated from jesus

But I am also a source of great tragedy

> i don't want to explain this

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> witches doesn't respect jesus or god

Creeps and theives never seem to like my presence

> in front of jesus they donot want to reveal their identity

But only if others are around with me

> it is related to church

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> if peoples have any questions ,they ask jesus....so if he can answer all the question which mean he can understand all question as well

Comment: Nope, but I like the creative thought.

Comment: **Ay dios mio!**

Comment: But I am also a source of great tragedy? Christ, it's empty!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> An Observer

I am a source of good ideas

> The root of the scientific method is observation

But I am also a source of great tragedy

> Seeing things one should not could lead to tragedy

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> Most curses come about through someone finding out a witch is a witch

Creeps and theives never seem to like my presence

> Witnessing their crimes

But only if others are around with me

> A witness alone results in a "my word versus yours" situation, unless another witness can confirm.

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> The question in fact being: What happened?

Comment: Great idea! But it's not it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are...

> A light bulb

Because...

I am a source of great ideas

> When the light bulb comes on (over one's head)

But I am also a source of great tragedy

> When the bulb burns out bad things can happen

Witches always find it funny to curse me

> I'm lost on this one unless maybe witch/light bulb jokes

Creeps and thieves never seem to like my presence

> Obviously they like the cover of darkness

But only if others are around with me

> Christmas tree lights mean Christmas presents to steal? (Would go with the previous clue.)

Most important of all, I am the mirror of a question

> Think mirror image of a question mark.

Comment: Mario Garcia has already given the same answer... Your answer does not seem to improve upon his idea..

Comment: @Sid You are correct. I thought I had looked through them all but somehow I missed his answer.

Comment: This is correct but is a duplicate. Your tradegy line is correct though.

Comment: -1, this is a duplicate.